# rubyで配列の中の重複した値を取り出し、並び替える方法

Tags: ruby

rubyで配列の中の重複した値を取り出し、
重複してる数が多い順に並び替えて配列として出力するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか。

`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 1,3,5,7,9, 1,3,5,7, 1,3,5, 1,3, 1]`
↓
`[1,3,5,7,9]`

Answer (score 2):

Ruby2.7 の`tally`を使ってみました。

```rb
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 1,3,5,7,9, 1,3,5,7, 1,3,5, 1,3, 1]
arr.tally.sort_by{|_,v| -v}.select{|i| i[1] > 1}.map(&:first)
```

=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

Answer (score 1):

以下のコードで実行できました。

```
ary
.select {|v| arr.count(v) > 1 }            # 要素数が複数個に満たないものを取り除く
.sort {|a,b| arr.count(b) - arr.count(a) } # 要素数が多い順にソート
.uniq                                      # 重複した値を取り除く
```

Answer (score 1):

書かれている仕様を愚直に処理してみました。

```
require 'test/unit'

def unique_ordered(list)
  list
    .group_by(&:itself)           # {1=>[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 2=>[2], 3=>[3, 3, 3, 3, 3], 4=>[4], 5=>[5, 5, 5, 5], 6=>[6], 7=>[7, 7, 7], 8=>[8], 9=>[9, 9]}
    .select { |_, v| v.size > 1 } # {1=>[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 3=>[3, 3, 3, 3, 3], 5=>[5, 5, 5, 5], 7=>[7, 7, 7], 9=>[9, 9]}
    .sort_by { |_, v| -v.size }   # [[1, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], [3, [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]], [5, [5, 5, 5, 5]], [7, [7, 7, 7]], [9, [9, 9]]]
    .map(&:first)                 # [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
end

class UniqueOrderedTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_unique_ordred
    input = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 1,3,5,7,9, 1,3,5,7, 1,3,5, 1,3, 1]
    assert_equal [1,3,5,7,9], unique_ordered(input)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

こんな感じで、どうでしょう？

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 1, 3, 5, 7, 1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 1]
arr.inject(Hash.new(1)) { |a, e| a[e] -= 1; a }.select { |k, v| v.nonzero? }.sort_by { |k, v| v }.map(&:first)    
=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

こんな感じでもいいかと思います。

```
ary = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 1,3,5,7,9, 1,3,5,7, 1,3,5, 1,3, 1]
ary
  .uniq
  .select {|v| ary.index(v) != ary.rindex(v) }
  .sort_by {|v| -ary.count(v) }
```